# All else equal, should an MLE estimation have a lower standard error than OLS?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, econometrics, standard-error, probit

If I have a model with Y$\in${0,1}, and am estimating y= $\beta$x+$\eta$

My understanding is if I use a probit model say, I am imposing structure on the DGP by assuming Y|x=$\eta$ is distributed normally, which should achieve the cramer-rao lower bound.

So is it the case that estimating the equation by ols vs probit, the latter (or even a logit?) should yield lower standard errors?

Comment: Why is the conditional variable distributed normally?

Comment: I was just saying for a probit specification, you can interpret it as the error being normally distributed, which is the same as the condtional variable being normal? or is that incorrect

Comment: Probit is for when the response variable is binomial.

Comment: yes the reponse is binomial, but then the error is normal, no?

Comment: No, that’s not how it works. How would you end up with a residual of 2, for instance?